# Nice url with pagenames in mvc?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, url, seo

I'm want to build a mvc framework in php, but i want url's like page1/sub-page-1/sub-page-sub-page-1/ how can this be done? Because normally if you build a MVC framework urls would be like controller/action/parameters?

**So, if  i have a page called blog, but also a controller called blog that these are not in conflict with each.**

Comment: You create URL notation, which gets transformed into a regular expressions. Then your routing mechanism goes through the list of patterns and match the URL against each of patterns till the first match.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should redirect all the traffic to the index.php with a .htaccess containing something like that :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

And after in the index.php, you have to parse the URL, starting like this :

```
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
```

Make explodes, parseUrl, ...

Comment: Yeah, products like Wordpress or Symfony2 are based on this. However check for `favicon.ico`  first. It might not exist but browsers brute-force it anyway for the apparent reason of Microsoft being popular at least somehow. No need for PHP to jump in the action, just place a zero-byte `favicon.ico` file into the directory at leas t (hint: `touch`)

Comment: What does that has to do with my question?

Answer (score 0):

You need top generate and manage those URLs by yourself. If you use Apache you can stablish a Rewrite rule into your .htaccess file so modrewrite redirects every request to index.php and so parsing the url within index.php include the code that should be run.

You can take a look to JOOMLA source code, specially to JRoute class.